# Custom index page when no query string

Tags: .htaccess

How can I set the default index page to first.html when there's no query string present?

```
www.myexample.com/?pg=456    -- should use index.html
www.myexample.com            -- should use first.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#when there are query strings#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
#Rewrite "/" to "index.html"#
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html? [NC,L]
#when there are no query strings#
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
#Rewrite "/" to "first.html"#
RewriteRule ^$ /first.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. +10 :) What's the difference between `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pg=.+ [NC]` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`? What's more reliable?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` is a condition to the rule, it matches against empty query strings **if no query string** , and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^pg=.+` is a diffrent condition, we use it to match agaist a specific query string **if query_string !=pg=foo**

Answer (score 2):

You can use in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pg=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ first.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. +10 :) What's the difference between `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pg=.+ [NC]` and `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`? What's more reliable?

Comment: With `!pg=.+` you test if the query string `pg` does not exist. While with `^$` you test that there is no query string.